# StopIteration error in python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, wolfram-mathematica, speech-recognition

I am using `wolframalpha` and `wit.ai` together and i am trying to build that `wolframalpha` fetch data from `wit.ai` audio instead of terminal text.

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import speech_recognition as sr
import wolframalpha
import sys

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)


WIT_AI_KEY = "NQYEITRO5GL2Q2MZFIJE4UHWVNQEUROW"
try:
    print("Wit.ai thinks you said " + r.recognize_wit(audio, key=WIT_AI_KEY))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Wit.ai could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Wit.ai service; {0}".format(e))


client = wolframalpha.Client('PR5756-H3EP749GGH')
print(r.recognize_wit(audio, key=WIT_AI_KEY))
res = client.query(r.recognize_wit(audio, key=WIT_AI_KEY))
print(next(res.results).text)
```

I am facing this error:

```
MacBook-Air:Documents exepaul$ python ak.py
2016-02-22 23:05:04.429 Python[3003:122880] 23:05:04.428 WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.
Say something!
Wit.ai thinks you said seven
seven
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ak.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(next(res.results).text)
StopIteration
```

How can I give data to wolframalpha api?

Comment: if you don't know that `next()` may raise `StopIteration` in Python; you should learn Python basics: it is likely that you have other glaring gaps. See https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Comment: does this work? `print(res.results[0].text)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StopIteration` is raised when generator is exhausted and has no more values, it's totaly ok to get one. But you need to handle it yourself:

```
try:
    print(next(res.results).text)
except StopIteration:
    print("No more suggesstions.")
```